# tumblr importer error wp 3.4.2

Tags: tumblr

i'm trying to import content from tumblr, in wp 3.4.2 i get an error not found
i can't get also the tumblr importer page
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tumblr-importer/
any idea?

Error Data:

*Import Tumblr Tumblr replied with an error: Not found. We couldn't find the page you were looking for. Find out why you may have encountered this error. Howdy! This importer allows you to import posts from your Tumblr account into your WordPress site. Firstly, you need to provide your email and password for Tumblr, so that WordPress can access your account. no php errors*

*tools - import - tumblr (An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.)*

Comment: Please add the actual screen error you're seeing as well as anything you see in the PHP logs.

Comment: Import Tumblr

Tumblr replied with an error:
Not found.

We couldn't find the page you were looking for.

Find out why you may have encountered
this error.

Howdy! This importer allows you to import posts from your Tumblr account into your WordPress site.

Firstly, you need to provide your email and password for Tumblr, so that WordPress can access your account. no php errors

Comment: tools - import - tumblr (An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.)

Comment: tumblr api has changed - http://engineering.tumblr.com/post/7541361718/introducing-tumblrs-new-api that's the cause probably the plugin should be modified

Answer (score 2):

The Tumblr importer is currently broken because they disabled access to their v1 API. We're working on it.

Comment: tx Otto , do you know when can we expect to have it working ?

Comment: It's a nearly total rewrite of the authentication mechanism (which now must use OAuth) and a lot of the API requests. So... not anytime soon. Weeks, not days.